# jQuery - I'm having trouble looping through elements by class and executing a function each time

Tags: jquery

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyt9o6b2/

HTML:

```
 <textarea class="TextArea" id="TextArea1">Text in block 1</textarea>
 <div class="PrintHelp" id="TextArea1PrintHelp"></div>
 <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
 <textarea class="TextArea" id="TextArea2">Text in block 2</textarea>
 <div class="PrintHelp" id="TextArea2PrintHelp"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
 function copy_to_print_helper(TextAreaID, PrintHelpID){
     $('#' + TextAreaID).text($('#' + PrintHelpID).val());
   }
   
 $('.TextArea').each(function(){
 copy_to_print_helper(this, this + 'PrintHelp')
 })
```

On PageLoad, I want to loop through all of my textarea elements of class 'TextArea' and then execute the copy_to_print_helper() function to copy that textarea's text into the corresponding div. I have very little experience with jQuery but I'm guessing I'm not far off - any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Should it get the element's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is with your use of `this` in the jQuery event handler. That will hold a reference to the Element object. However in the `copy_to_print_helper` you expect this value to be a string which can be appended to the `id` of the element to form a selector, which is not the case. You would need to access the `id` property of the object for that to work - but even then there's a better approach.

Use the `this` reference of the object itself to get the properties of the `textarea`, and also to find the related element in the DOM. This completely avoids the need for any incremental `id` attributes which you dynamically target at runtime, making the HTML and JS code much more simple and reliable:

```js
function copy_to_print_helper(textarea) {
  $(textarea).next('.PrintHelp').text(textarea.value);
}

$('.TextArea').each(function() {
  copy_to_print_helper(this)
})
```

```css
.PrintHelp {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="TextArea">Text in block 1</textarea>
<div class="PrintHelp"></div>

<textarea class="TextArea">Text in block 2</textarea>
<div class="PrintHelp"></div>
```

Taking this a step further, the logic can be made more succinct by providing a function to `text()` which returns the value to be displayed in each `div` using an implicit loop over every element in the collection:

```js
$('.print-help').text(function() {
  return $(this).prev('.textarea').val();
});
```

```css
.print-help { margin-bottom: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea">Text in block 1</textarea>
<div class="print-help"></div>

<textarea class="textarea">Text in block 2</textarea>
<div class="print-help"></div>
```